# Array Associations Python

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, tree

I have a CSV file that mimics a tree diagram looks like this:

```
A,B #A is associated to B

A,C #A is associated to C

B,D #B is associated to D

B,E #B is associated to E

C,F #C is associated to F

C,G #C is associated to G
```

A is the root(top of the tree) B & C are the Branches, D,E,F,G are the leaves(children of the branch)

I want to know if there is a way to put this in an array with its associations?

Comment: Can you post your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the file `my.csv` contains the example input you gave, this code records the graph structure in two simple Python `dict` objects:

```
parent = {}
children = {}
with open( 'my.csv', 'rt' ) as fh:
    for line in fh:
        # strip the comments and line endings
        if '#' in line: line = line[ :line.index( '#' ) ]
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            # record the association
            node, subnode = line.split( ',', 1 )
            parent[ subnode ] = node
            children.setdefault( node, [] ).append( subnode )
```

The syntax `children['A']` then allows you to look up the list of child nodes belonging to node `'A'`, and the syntax `parent['B']` lets you go the other way, and look up the parent of node `'B'`. Or you can pretty-print the whole thing with:

```
for node, subnodes in sorted( children.items() ):
    print( '%r : %r' % ( node, subnodes ) )
```

Output:

```
'A' : ['B', 'C']
'B' : ['D', 'E']
'C' : ['F', 'G']
```

Comment: I get a too many values to unpack error for node,subnode=line.split(',')

Comment: That must be down to irregularities in the input file. It runs for me using your example input, and if the input *is* exactly as represented in that example (i.e. exactly 2 comma-separated items per line, no trailing commas) then you won't get that error.  I've added a `maxsplit=1` argument to `split()`, which should get rid of the error in cases where there happen to be more than 2 comma-separated items on a line: the resulting child node "name" will be wrong, but at least you can then inspect it to see what and where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Using [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/) to make a digraph and [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) to plot a image of the digraph:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

text =\
"""A,B
A,C
B,D
B,E
C,F
C,G"""

graph = nx.DiGraph()
for i in text.split('\n'):
    graph.add_edge(i[0], i[2])

nx.draw(graph, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

Note this line: `graph.add_edge(i[0], i[2])`
If the node didn't exists in this graph, it will automatically be created.

Plot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A natural structure for holding your information is a **dictionary** where the key for each entry is a node name (eg, C) that occurs as on the left of a row in your csv file and the value of that dict entry is an array that ultimately contains the names of all the nodes that are immediate children of that key (eg, [F, G]).

So as you process each row of your csv file (eg B, D), check whether the first element (eg, B) is already a key within the dict.  If not, add an entry to the dict with key=B and value=[D].  If it already exists, append the second element to that key's array value.  For example, when you reach the data line B, E you would find the entry for B (B => [D]) and append E onto its value, yielding [D, E].

When you are done, a node is the root of a tree if the name of that node never appears in any entry's array value.  If more than one node has this property, then each of those nodes is the root of a tree in a forest of trees.